# How to fix JSONException Error in Volley library?

Tags: android, arrays, json, android-volley

I am trying to send a JSON object request with two parameters and in response trying to get an array from the api call. However, I am getting exception parse error in Error listener. A post request is sent when the button is clicked. The func takes two parameters but fails to get response, the function directly goes to on response error listener

```
private void validate_log(String num) {
    /*buttonNumCheck.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    final ProgressBar pBar=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBarLogin);
    pBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);*/
    buttonNumCheck.setInProgress(true);
    buttonNumCheck.setEnabled(false);
    final String Org_id="81";
    final String url="http://xya/api";
    RequestQueue rq=Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    JSONObject js=new JSONObject();
    try {

        js.put("parm1", num);
        js.put("parm2", Org_id);

        final String requestBody=js.toString();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq=new JsonObjectRequest(


            Request.Method.POST, url, js,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    buttonNumCheck.setEnabled(true);
                    buttonNumCheck.setInProgress(false);
                    String stresponse=response.toString();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"REPOSE="+response,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    System.out.println("RESPONSE= "+response);

                    try {


                        JSONArray heroArray = response.getJSONArray("");

                            // Toast.makeText(DeviceCheck_Activity.this, "Welcome Back"+ [1], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.e("Error", "Response Error", e);


                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            Toast.makeText(DeviceCheck_Activity.this, "Response error= " + error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            /*mdToast=MDToast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Oops something went wrong!!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, MDToast.TYPE_ERROR);
            mdToast.show();*/
            buttonNumCheck.setInProgress(false);
            buttonNumCheck.setEnabled(true);

            Log.e("Error", "Response Error", error);


        }
    }) {


        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers=new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

            return headers;
        }

    };

    jsonObjReq.setShouldCache(false);
    jsonObjReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(20 * 1000, 0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    rq.add(jsonObjReq);

}
```

**The error response I am getting is**

> com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value [{"store_id":11,"store_name":"Gomati District Main Store"},{"store_id":13,"store_name":"Main Seed Store"}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: `[` represents **json array** node.

`{` represents **json object** node

Comment: Your Response is jsonArray not jsonobject. You need to add JsonArrayRequest  not JsonObjectRequest. You can follow This link 
https://android--examples.blogspot.com/2017/02/android-volley-json-array-request.html

Comment: none of answers works for you ??????????????

Comment: Nope didn't worked but I got the solution from another page, I have posted the solution anyways thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Your Problem can be solved in 2 ways :

> First:)

Using **JSONArrayRequest** instead of **JSONbjectRequest**.

Your **JSONObjectRequest** returns an **JSONObject** response while your response is an **JSONArray** therefore java can not convert it and your application crashes.

**Change you request as below:**

```
    JSONArrayRequest jsonArrReq=new JSONArrayRequest(//changed
        Request.Method.POST, url, js,
        new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                   JSONArray heroArray = response;//changeed
                  /* rest of your code */

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("Error", "Response Error", e);
            }

        }
    },
    jsonArrReq.setShouldCache(false);
    jsonArrReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(20 * 1000, 0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    rq.add(jsonArrReq);
```

> Second :)

Using **StringRequest** instead of **JSONObjectRequest**. String request returns an String response which lets you do what ever you want with your response.

Change you request as  below :

```
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                          JSONArray heroArray = new JSONArray(response);
                              /* rest of your code */
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                     Log.e("Error", "Response Error", error);
                         /*rest of your code */
                    }
                }) {

                    @Override
                    public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
                        try {
                            return requestBody == null ? null : js.getBytes("utf-8");
                        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                            VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s", js, "utf-8");
                            return null;
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                        String responseString = "";
                        if (response != null) {
                            responseString = String.valueOf(response.statusCode);
                            // can get more details such as response.headers
                        }
                        return Response.success(responseString, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
                    }
                };

            } 

stringRequest.setShouldCache(false);
stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(20 * 1000, 0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
rq.add(stringRequest);
```

Comment: That a JSONRequest expects JSON two ways is a really overlooked thing. I have an API that returns "ok" And i could not for the life of me see that there was any errors in the JSON syntax. Overlooked that it was not the request it was compaining about. It was the response. Thank you for a great answer!. The exact exception I was facing was "JsonObject volley value ok value ok of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject" Leaving it here in the hope that Google will guide more people with that exception to this great answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the JsonArrayRequest like thisas your response is JsonArray .

```
 JsonArrayRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, js,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        buttonNumCheck.setEnabled(true);
                        buttonNumCheck.setInProgress(false);
                        String stresponse = response.toString();                   
                        try {
                            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject object = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                String id = object.getString("store_id");
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                           e.printStackTrace();
                            Log.e("Error", "Response Error", e);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: I tried adding Jsonarray Request it corresponds to error: incompatible types: JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray due to js.put

Answer (score 0):

Tried all the solutions didn't worked but thank you guys for your help. I actually found the solution from another question posted in stack overflow page. Here is the solution:

```
RequestQueue requestQueue=Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override

        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                //JSONArray jsonArray_1=new JSONArray(response);
                System.out.println("RESPONSE= " + response);

                JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(response);
                json_stringarr=new String[jsonArray.length()];
                if(jsonArray.length()>0) {
                    for (int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject1=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        //String web_page=jsonObject1.getString("awb_no");
                        String store_id=jsonObject1.getString("store_id");
                        String store_name=jsonObject1.getString("store_name");
                        json_stringarr[i]=store_id+" - "+store_name;
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "RESPOBBSE= " + json_stringarr[i], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        System.out.println("JSON ARRAY=" + json_stringarr[i]);
                        System.out.println("JSON Object=" + jsonObject1);

                    }

                }
                else{

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Login ceredentils are incorrect",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override

        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            MDToast mdToast=MDToast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, MDToast.TYPE_WARNING);
            mdToast.show();
            error.printStackTrace();

        }

    }) {

        @Override
        public byte[] getBody() {
     //     String body="{\"param1\":"+num+",\"param2\":\"81"\"}";
            String body="{\"parm1\":"+num+",\"parm2\":\"81\"}";
            return body.getBytes();
        }

        /*@Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("param1", num);
            params.put("param2", Org_id);
            return params;
        }*/

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers=new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            return headers;
        }

    };
```

I did it by sending a String request and then overriding the getBody() method and then it worked like a charm. Thanks again for all your help.